# Does the Tanakh ever require a dress code for prayer?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, clothing

Does the Tanakh teach that a certain minimum dress code is required for prayer? I'm under the impression that the Tanakh doesn't teach such, but that it originates from other sources. If I'm incorrect, however, and the Tanakh does address this, where?

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to specify which aspects of conduct/dress during prayer you specifically have in mind. Covering nakedness, has a different source than covering one's head, and that different than the source for not dressing shabbily and so on. As currently formulated, I would say your question is a bit too broad to be able to be addressed succinctly.

Comment: @Deuteronomy If I reworded my question to ask if the Tanakh ever addresses the need to dress a certain way when praying in general (i.e., any of the scenarios that you mentioned would qualify), would that be acceptable? I'm wondering if the Torah (or, more broadly, the Tanakh) addresses such at all, so I'm wanting to see if such regulations are present in the Tanakh.

Comment: out of the topics I've mentioned: not praying/reciting scriptural passages in front of nakedness is tethered to Deut. 23:15, not wearing shabby clothes during prayer is tethered to Psalms 29:2, wearing a headcovering is more in the realm of custom... none of these "regulations" are explicit in the Torah/Tanakh, neither is formal organized and structured prayer itself for that matter.

Comment: How directly would you want scriptural references to be connected? The Kohen ministers barefoot and prayer is related to sacrifices but we are not barefoot. There would need to be some connections drawn.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Psalm 29:2 says that we should give G-d glory and worship Him in the beauty of holiness, which could have implications for clothing when praying. Of course, the verse mentions neither praying nor clothing, but such could be involved. As for Deuteronomy 23:15, I'm not seeing how it's about praying, nakedness, or clothing, as it seems to be about slaves. (I might be missing something, though.) If my question is still confusing, perhaps this would be a better-worded question: "Does the Tanakh ever dictate a dress code for any form of prayer?" Would this question work? I can edit it.

Comment: Like I said, they are "tethered" to those passages. The plain meaning does not necessarily teach these. In Rabbinic Judaism many passages are used as support but not proofs for a practice. Formal, organized, prayer is not something that is made explicit in Tanakh, so it is hard to imagine how or why a dress code for something never made explicit would be mentioned. The closest approximate to this might be the linens the Leviim wore while singing, or the special clothes of the Kohanim and/or Kohen Gadol during Temple service, which on occasion may invoke some recitation.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.17b.5 The Holy One, Blessed be He, wrapped Himself in a prayer shawl like a prayer leader and showed Moses the structure of the order of the prayer. He said to him: Whenever the Jewish people sin, let them act before Me in accordance with this order. Let the prayer leader wrap himself in a prayer shawl and publicly recite the thirteen attributes of mercy, and I will forgive them.

Comment: I've edited the question to better clarify that my question is whether the Tanakh addresses dress codes for prayer at all.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I see. The specific instruction doesn't come directly from Tanakh, but broad principles from it are used when dictating how to dress. Feel free to make that into an answer, if you'd like. Thanks!